# hibernate select data from two tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables: `authors` and `books`

**Author:**

```
 @Entity
 @Table (name="authors")
 public class Author implements  java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String name;
private String lastName;
/*book list*/
private Set<Book> books= new HashSet<Book>(0);

public Author() {
}

public Author(String name, String lastName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Author(String name, String lastName, Set<Book> books) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.books = books;
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "AUTHOR_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "AUTHOR_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "AUTHOR_LASTNAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "author")
public Set<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}
}
```

**Book:**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book implements  java.io.Serializable {
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Author author;
public Book() {
}
public Book(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Book(String name, Author author) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
}
@Id
@Column(name = "BOOK_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "BOOK_NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID",nullable = false)
public Author getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
public void setAuthor(Author author) {
    this.author = author;
}
}
```

In  my book's table I have field with id `author`. How can I get all books from one author? How Can I solve it?
Must I use `HQL` or other methods? I am beginner in this.

Comment: HQL or Criteria API could help you

Comment: Try `Author author = session.find(authorId)` then `session.createQuery("select b from Book b where b.author = :a").setParameter("a", author).list()`. Use google to find more examples how to use HQL and createQuery

Comment: PS. Good tutorial here: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/

Answer (score 0):

first you need to the mapping between two entities.

### Author class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="author")
private Set<Book> books= new HashSet<Book>(0);
```

### Book class

```
@ManyToOne
private Author author;
```

after that you can use a simple criteria query to retrieve the relevant records.

Answer (score -1):

I wont help you with the code here but the logic.. 
The very first thing you need to do is build a relationship between Author and Books using the annotations @OneToMany or @ManyToOne depending on your structure.

Next use the Author Class Object to retrive the list of Books.